# How to empty an array using ES6 Array.fill()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a variable like below

```
var arr = [undefined];
```

How to make `arr` is equal to `[]` using ES6 `Array.fill()`?

**Edit:**
I am doing a katas and got a test case like

```
it('fill only changes content, adds no new elements', function() { 
   const arr = [undefined].fill(); 
   assert.deepEqual(arr, []); 
});
```

Confused how to make it. I can do it removing undefined. but is there any nice way to do it besides that. just curious

Comment: Why do you want to use `fill` to empty it? Also, `fill` cannot shrink an Array

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve, you might get better ways to do it ?

Comment: I know but I am doing a katas and got a test case like `it('fill only changes content, adds no new elements', function() {
    const arr = [undefined].fill();
    
    assert.deepEqual(arr, []);
  });` . confused how to make it. I can do it removing `undefined`. but is there any nice way to do it besides that. just curious.

Comment: @nmrony Can you please edit your question and include the code and clarify your question?

Comment: I feel @thefourtheye 's comment should be added to `MDN`

Comment: Just remove the `undefined` then there is no content which can be changed by `.fill()`: `const arr = [].fill(0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to make `[undefined]` equal to `[]` using ES6 `Array.fill()`?

You cannot, as [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) does not alter the length of the array.

It looks like [they really want you to remove the `undefined`](https://github.com/tddbin/es6katas.org/issues/9), or use something else like `arr.splice(0, 1);`.

Comment: Accepting this answer for mentioning Github link

Answer (score 0):

You can only fill the array with undefined values

```
[1,2,3].fill(undefined);
```

But the array has always the properties 0, 1 and 2 also with undefined value.

So you can't remove properties using fill